# How to write a list in one excel cell using python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

this is my list

```
list=['a','b','c']
```

when using this code

```
with open('commentafterlink.csv', 'w') as f:


     f.write("%s\n" % list)
```

it stores each token of list in a one cell but i need to store whole list in one cell.where is the problem?

Comment: look for `join()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You are not writing an Excel file, but a CSV file (that Excel knows how to import).

2) You are writing to the CSV file as if it was a text file, without respecting the semantics of CSV. CSV means ["comma-separated values"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). If it contains the text `['a','b','c']`, it will be interpreted as three columns: `['a'` and `'b'` and `'c']`. You would need to quote the value in order to do it right; the default quote in CSV is a double quote. So if you write `"['a','b','c']"`, this would be imported into Excel as one cell. However,

3) You are writing CSV file by hand, which means it is very easy to get the format wrong (e.g. forget to escape something that needs to be escaped). In general, whenever you are writing a file with an established format, it is worth checking if the format has a library that knows how to handle it. Python natively knows how to write CSV files using the `csv` module, and it knows how to write Excel files using packages you can install using `pip`, such as `xlwt`.

Here is how you write a CSV file correctly:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

import csv
with open('commentafterlink.csv', 'w') as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    writer.writerow([str(my_list)])
```

**Note:** It is a Bad Thing to overwrite Python's built-in variables, such as `list`.

(I see another answerer has already provided you the Excel-specific solution using `xlwt`.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
import xlwt 
from xlwt import Workbook 
# Workbook is created 
wb = Workbook() 

# add_sheet is used to create sheet. 
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1') 
# sheet1.write(1, 0, ' '.join(list)) 
# if you want the output to be ['a','b','c']
sheet1.write(1, 0, str(list)) 
wb.save('xlwt example.xls')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using [`join()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm):

```
lst=['a','b','c']
with open('commentafterlink.csv', 'w') as f:
 f.write("%s\n" % "".join(lst))
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image]

**EDIT**:

Using [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr):

```
import xlsxwriter

lst=['a','b','c']                                        # avoid using list keyword   
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('commentafterlink.xlsx')  # create/read the file
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()                     # adding a worksheet
worksheet.write('A1', repr(lst))                         # write repr(lst) to cell A1
workbook.close()                                         # close the file
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image: out]

Comment: output should be :  ['a','b','c']  not abc